# swift vapor routes error - Type has no member 'save'

Tags: swift, routes, vapor

I am getting following errors in routes.swift -
I can also post other files if you need -

```
import Routing
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

 public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
 router.get { req -> Future <View> in
 let Newyorker = Pizza(id: 5, name: "statinisland", description: "impracticaljokers", price: 55)
let Traditional = Pizza(id: 5, name: "rome", description: "pope", price: 55)
return try req.view().render("welcome",["pizza":[Newyorker,Traditional]])
}

 router.post(Pizza.self, at: "add") { req, pizza ->
 Future<Response> in
return Pizza.save(on:req).map(to:Response.self) { Pizza
    in
    return req.redirect(to: "/")
  }
 }
 /*Error - Type 'Pizza' has no member 'save'; did you mean 'name'?
Replace 'save' with 'name' */  
  }
```

unable to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Pizza.save(on: req)` to `pizza.save(on: req)` since you want to save the instance sent to the closure

Comment: done that - now error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Perhaps remove the `map(to:)` part

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson - Nick's answer helped. I changedpizza model to  "struct Pizza:SQLiteModel, Content" and the error went away. See my previous question. This question was an extension to the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to changing `Pizza.save(on:req)` to `pizza.save(on:req)` as per the earlier answer, you will need to conform your `Pizza` model to `Content`. Something like:

```
struct Pizza:SQLiteModel, Content
```

Or, better

```
final class Pizza:SQLiteModel, Content
```